# Подача импульса в конкретную кость Unreal Engine 5

Tags: разработка-игр, unreal-engine-5

С недавнего времени увлекся Unreal Engine5.
Скачал с инета персонажа - собака из boston dynamics, у нго есть:

- mesh asset
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- skeleton
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- physics asset.
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нейросеть будет управлять агентом игры, и каждый тик, опираясь на окружающую информацию предпринимать решение о подачи импульса в какую то свою конечность.

Я не хочу заранее делать ЦЕЛУЮ анимацию шага ногой, я хочу чтобы нейросеть сама определила, как надо управлять всеми ногами.

Конечность робота НЕ МОЖЕТ моментально повернуться на 90 градусов. Мне необходимо реализовать подачу физического импульса в кость. Или предложите свой вариант.

И на данный момент у меня проблема с тем, чтобы передавать импульс, в часть скелета с целью его поворота например. И от вас требуется помочь мне именно с этим.

У меня не получается управлять частями скелета из blueprints:

- Я создаю blueprint, внутри которого есть сцена, на которую я добавил mesh_asset моей собачки. Далее (в боковом меню blueprint-а) в physics_component я указываю physics_asset собаки, а в skeleton -> skeleton_asset.

И вот проблема:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Да, я хотел импульс подавать, но пока что даже так не получается...